# QGIS - comma separated values or link table - m-n relations

Tags: qgis, database, relation

Is there a way in QGIS to assign multiple values to another value without creating additional columns? Using the example of owners to parcels, I would like to set the reference to several parcels in one column, e.g. separated by comma.

| fid | owner | fk_parcel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Miller | 1, 2 |
| 2 | Young | 3, 2 |

connected by foregin key fk_parcel

| fid | parcel | area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dakota | 45 |
| 2 | york | 352 |
| 3 | bristol | 768 |

Or are link tables necessary? If so, how would that look?

Comment: It is possible to have a field with comma separated values (by just putting them as a string). I think you need to clarify your need: how are the related fk IDs meant to be assigned for each owner ?

Comment: yes, the parcel with the fid 1 is assigned to the owner with the fid 1. As well as the parcel 2, wich is assigned to the owner with fid 1 and owner with fid 2... and so on.